# What would the situationists think of this rule?

Tags: aesthetics, marxism

Do what one will to maximize ones own sense of overcoming mundane life.

I understand their ideas about the situation were meant to prod people out of their mundane lives. The situation  being, IIRC, a construct of the activist which itself has no workable definition.

IMO situationism then, failed when the May riots did, on the grounds that this artistic movement could only be gauged on its supra artistic revolutionary success, or lack of.

So my formulation is broadly situ like, but more individual, and more resigned.

Comment: For my $0.02, it's not a bad maxim as they go! :) --Is there any chance you could share a little more about the context and motivations of the problem you're encountering here?

Comment: Could you unpack what you mean by "the situation" or what it means to the SI movement?

Comment: gonna be tricky, will get back to after sleep :)

Comment: I think this is part of what they were after with their *detournement*!